# Is it possible to update NPM using NPM?

Tags: node.js, npm

I was having a problem with a node module that I installed and I think it is because my node version was out of date. I just went through the process of updating and it's pretty mind-numbingly tedious. I know that the node package manager lets you install updates for other modules, but is it possible to update itself using NPM?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Is like another `npm` package.

```
npm update -g npm
```

Simple.

Comment: Just when I started typing it. =) But it looks like user3513020 wants to update `node.js` version, not `npm`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have read it carelessly. I would suggest a version manager like [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). Is the cleanest method IMO.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

take the answer from this article: http://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs

Comment: It's a bad practice to use `npm` and `n` with `sudo`.